# IIS web site with httpplatformhandler on specific route does not redirect to the nextjs site

Tags: next.js, iis, httpplatformhandler

I am trying to host a nextjs website on iis here is my set up .

1. Website with web.config hosted under default site

[image]

2. Contents of web.config which causes nextjs site . On access of http://localhost/AppWithNode1/SimpleErrorView it should redirect to the nextjs site.
   [image]
3. On navigate to the http://localhost/AppWithNode1/SimpleErrorView
   it shows the nextjs 404 error page

[image]

the console shows 404 for the js and css assets too.

4. I have tried with adding a basepath to the nextjs.config.mjs and a assetPrefix still get the same error . Im not sure what else is missing to get this to work ? .Any help would be appreciated Thanks .
   [image]

Edit:

[image]

Output after rewrite
[image]

Output from the port hosted via httpplatformhandler

[image]

Log file generate output
[image]

Comment: I don't know about IIS, but you are using NextJS as a server or static page? It seems like a problem to forward to the correct localhost port.

Comment: @RafaelFernandes Nothing wrong with port. It’s just how to config Next.js to properly handle the extra components from URLs.

Comment: Any suggestions @LexLi ? I have tried adding a middleware and doing a rewrite the page gets redirected but the js/css assets dont load .  I have edited my middleware code in the question post

Comment: Now iam trying to intercept the js/css to rewrite that with the port number . Not sure if this is the right way to go about it

Comment: My test shows that only `basePath` is needed to change, and nothing else. I am not sure why you made all the other changes, but maybe roll them back now.